# validation accuracy is 0 with Keras fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-2

I recently upgraded to Keras 2.2.2. The validation accuracy is zero for all training epochs. My training data has data samples in 2 categories i.e., train_data_dir has 2 subfolders. My validation data (i.e., val_data_dir) has data samples in 1 category only but it contains 2 subfolders (one for each category) with no data samples in one of the subfolders. I used to get a meaningful non-zero value for the validation accuracy with an earlier version of Keras. Please help me spot the issue my code (below) and Keras 2.2.2

Below is part of my code:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
batch_size = batch_size, 
class_mode = "categorical")    

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
val_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
batch_size = batch_size, 
class_mode = "categorical",
save_to_dir = 'home/dir')

nb_train_samples = train_generator.n
nb_validation_samples = validation_generator.n

sample_steps = int(nb_train_samples/batch_size)
validation_steps = int(nb_validation_samples/batch_size)


parallel_model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch = sample_steps,
epochs = 1,
validation_data = validation_generator,    
validation_steps = validation_steps,
callbacks=[early])
```

Comment: I am assuming you checked whether `nb_validation_samples` (and subsequently, `validation_steps`) are non-zero? Also, if you just iterate over the `validation_generator`, will you get the expected batches and targets?

Comment: Hi @dennlinger yes checked that nb_validation_samples and validation_steps are non-zero. Yes, validation_generator gives expected batched and targets.

Comment: I am assuming the train loss also decreases? And does the validation *loss* decrease (i.e. is only the accuracy 0, or also the loss?)?

Comment: @dennlinger Only val accuracy is zero. Training loss, val loss and training accuracy are also meaningful numbers and trend in the right direction with training.

Comment: I know this Q&A debugging is not really well-received here, but maybe you can share how you compile your model? I just want to make sure the right metrics are passed (or show the otherwise relevant code where you get the validation accuracy)...

Comment: parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model_final, gpus = 4)

parallel_model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9), metrics = ['acc', 'categorical_accuracy'])

Comment: @dennlinger Thanks for trying to help! I've posted it above.