# Keras Validation Accuracy is Zero but other metrics are normal

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am working on a computer vision problem in keras and I have run into a an interesting problem. My val_acc is 0.0000e+00. This is especially interesting as my other metrics such as loss, acc, and val_loss all are acting normally.

This started happening when I switched from the Sequence data_generator to a custom one that I'm pretty sure is working as intended.
 My issue is very similar to this one [validation accuracy is 0 with Keras fit_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197351/validation-accuracy-is-0-with-keras-fit-generator) but no answer was reached in that thread.
I have checked to make sure my activations and loss metrics are appropriate for my particular problem. I am using: `loss='categorical_crossentropy' metrics=['accuracy']` and am attempting to predict the month that a certain spectrogram comes from.
The validation data is being loaded in the exact same way as the training data so I really can't figure out whats happening also even random guessing should give a 1/12 val_acc right? It can't be zero.

Here is my model architecture:

```py
x = (Convolution2D(32,5,5,activation='relu',input_shape=(501,501,1)))(input_img)
x = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(x)
x = (Convolution2D(32,5,5,activation='relu'))(x)
x = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(x)
x = (Dropout(0.25))(x)
x = (Flatten())(x)
x = (Dense(128,activation='relu'))(x)
x = (Dropout(0.5))(x)
classify = (Dense(12,activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = 0.001,l2 = 0.001)))(x)

model = Model(input_img,classify)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='nadam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and here is my call to fit_generator:

```py
model.fit_generator(generator = pd.data_generator(folder,'train'),
                    validation_data = pd.data_generator(folder,'test'),
                    steps_per_epoch=(120),
                    validation_steps=(24),
                    nb_epoch=20,
                    verbose=1,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback,early_stop_callback])
```

and finally here is the important part of my data generator:

```py
if mode == 'test':
        print('test')
        while True:

            for things in up.unpickle_batch(folder,50,6000,7200): #The last 1200 things in batches of 50
                random.shuffle(things)
                test_spect = []
                test_months = []
                for thing in things:
                    test_spect.append(thing.spect) #GET BATCH DATA
                    test_months.append(thing.month-1) #this is is here because the months go from 1-12 but should go from 0-11 for to_categorical   
                x_test = np.asarray(test_spect) #PREPARE BATCH DATA
                x_test =  x_test.astype('float32')
                x_test /= np.amax(x_test) #- 0.5
                X_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1,501, 501,1))


                Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(test_months,12)

                yield X_test,Y_test #RETURN BATCH DATA
```

Comment: Try evaluating it manually. Take a single batch of size 10 or something like that, run model.predict on it, and print out both the predictions and the ground truth. Hopefully that should give you more information about what's going on.

Comment: This helped! I found out I wasn't properly feeding in random data because all the test cases were the same month also for some reason my model was guessing the same month for every input leading to it being wrong every time! Hence, 0 val_acc.

Answer (score 0):

Check for bad data.

Make sure your data is what you think it is -- shuffled, distributed the same as your validation and/or test set, free of misleading/erroneous/contradictory samples. You can probably generate a failproof dataset (e.g. distinguish dark images from light ones, or sharp versus blurry) and prove that everything but the data is OK. If you can't, then look more closely at your code. This, however, sounds like a data problem.

I just fixed a similar problem in a simple 3-layer MLP network for which training loss & accuracy were heading in reasonable directions, validation loss was following training loss (but lagging) yet validation accuracy hovered at zero. There was an off-by-one error in my training dataset generation (a sampling script from a larger set) that meant that 1 sample in the entire block of samples for one type had the label for the next block for a different type. 499 correct samples out of 500 was insufficient to keep the training on track.